# setup.py generates /usr/bin wrappers with a "#!." shebang

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to package a Python application. The package script runs in a chroot, and invokes setup.py (setuptools-based) as follows:

```
python setup.py install --root="$pkgdir"
```

However, the executable wrappers (to be placed in `/usr/bin`) start with a `#!.` shebang line, i.e. with a dot instead of the path to the Python interpreter.

Why does this happen and how to work around this (without manually patching the generated scripts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setuptools attempts to use the Python interpreter binary used to invoke it for generating its wrappers. To this goal, it [invokes distutils](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/4876dbb7f09b02eb0d513837d7c27d08b095cdce/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py#L33), which then [queries `sys.executable`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/76b387bf7402863c5e64e3459e2f91ddc3b9d2d3/Lib/distutils/command/build.py#L120).

In certain circumstances (such as this particular situation), `sys.executable` can be an empty string. The most likely reason is that the packaging operation runs in a `chroot`, which does not allow Python access to `/proc`.

`os.path.normpath('')` evaluates to `'.'`, which then gets propagated all the way back to setuptools, and ends up in a shebang.

The workaround is to invoke Python using an absolute path:

```sh
/usr/bin/python setup.py install --root="$pkgdir"
```

Python can then get grab its own path from `argv[0]`, thus allowing setuptools to generate correct shebang lines.

Comment: In bash, you could do `\`which python\` setup.py install` etc. to substitute the full path of the default Python into the command.